# How to use #states with a container element?

Tags: 7, javascript

I come from read this [Using the Drupal 7 Form API states system to create conditions between form elements](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/using-the-drupal-7-form-api-states-system-to-create-conditions-between-form-elements/2014-01-20) and I'm able to use the #states with an input element like the title (textfield element), the problem is that if I try to use a container element the #states doesn't works.

This code works:

```
$form['field_courriels_des_autres']['#states']['disabled']['input[name="title"]']['filled'] = TRUE;
```

This code doesn' works:

```
$form['field_preciser']['#states']['enabled']['select[name="field_salle"]']['value'] = 'other';
```

I think that the problem is that the `field_salle` is a container.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for fieldsets (known core issue), it's probably the same for containers

Comment: @clive any clues to solve this?

Comment: IIRC, I gave up about an hour into trying the various (broken) batches available to fix it. I think I went with some custom JS in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's been mentioned, the `#states` property doesn't work for fieldsets, containers.
You need some JS here, e.g:

**The form**

```
$form['promo_code_trigger'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => ['id' => ['promo-code-add-el']],
  'data' => [
    '#markup' => t('Add promotional code'),
  ]
];

$form['promo_code_wrapper'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => ['promo-code-add-el-triggered'],
    'class' => ['hidden'],
  ],
];
```

**JS**

```
$("#promo-code-add-el").on("click", function (e) {
  $('#' + e.target.id + "-triggered").toggleClass('hidden');
  $('#' + e.target.id).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

States indeed doesn't work with containers yet, because containers don't have necessary wrapper classes (`.js-form-item` or `.js-form-wrapper`). However you can do a workaround to get `#states` API to work with containers. Here is working code example from Drupal 9:

```
$form['container'] = [
  '#prefix' => '<div class="js-form-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="field_name"]' => ['value' => 'your_conditional_value_here'],
    ],
  ],
];
```